# How to add a image link to javascript

Tags: geoserver, javascript

I have some problem with my script.

I want to add my picture link. I save the picture link at some table in geoserver

this is my script

```
<div id='gambar'> <img src:'"+response.features[i].properties.gambar+"' 'style="width:70px;height:70px"' ></div>
```

Comment: This looks HTML, from where is it being called?

Comment: Also, how are you adding a table to geoserver? Do you mean some kind of database? What is the schema and attributes? Which service on your geoserver instance are you using?

Comment: yes this is some function from HTML,